# Django CSRF verfication failed

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf, django-csrf

I am new to Django and I have a problem with CSRF verification. I have so far created Django POST forms that are successful and have no CSRF errors. But when I try to create the following form, I get CSRF verification failure: "CSRF token missing or incorrect".

```
{% for a in answers %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <form class="" action="." method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="{{ a.answer }}" name={{a.answer_id}}></input>
    </form>
    <p>Number of votes: {{ a.votes }}</p>
{% empty %}
    <p>There are no answers for the poll</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is what the models look like:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here is what the view function for that form looks like (so far I haven't added any code to process the post request):

```
def poll(request, question_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pass
    poll = Question.objects.get(id=question_id)
    answers = poll.answer_set.order_by()
    context = {'poll' : poll, 'answers' : answers}
    return render(request, 'polls/poll.html', context)
```

Basically, for each question there are multiple answers. I want to allow the user to click the button associated to a particular answer. Once the user clicks a button, I want to increase the vote for that answer in the database (I haven't added the code to do this yet, but this is the goal). I then want the page to reload with the newly added vote.

[image: Here is just an example of what this looks like visually]

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or what I am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The csrf token goes inside the form:

```
<form class="" action="." method="post">
 {% csrf_token %} <!--here goes the token-->
    <input type="submit" value="{{ a.answer }}" name={{a.answer_id}}></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Yes, I tried that and I get the same error.

Comment: Did you reload the page?

Comment: This is basically correct - but the code above has a few problems on top. First there is not python form which might validate the CSRF token, second the are many forms (because you have the form tag inside of a loop). This can not work this way. Create a proper python form that only needs one form in HTML to work around the glitches.

Comment: @dahrens As I understad there's no problem with many forms each one with its own csrf. You say it won't work because it's a loop?

Comment: @guillermochamorro It works now! Once I reloaded the page, it worked. I didn't know I had to do that, thanks!